# Is there a workaround to open URLs containing underscores in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I'm using open-uri to open URLs.

```
resp = open("http://sub_domain.domain.com")
```

If it contains underscore I get an error:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part: sub_domain.domain.com (or bad hostname?)
```

I understand that this is because according to RFC URLs can contain only letters and numbers. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This looks like a bug in URI, and uri-open, HTTParty and many other gems make use of URI.parse.

Here's a workaround:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'open-uri'

def hopen(url)
  begin
    open(url)
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    host = url.match(".+\:\/\/([^\/]+)")[1]
    path = url.partition(host)[2] || "/"
    Net::HTTP.get host, path
  end
end

resp = hopen("http://dear_raed.blogspot.com/2009_01_01_archive.html")
```

Comment: This is an ugly hack, but it works. The problem is that one of our partners forces us to use this domain name and we even have to add it to the hosts files on all servers, because it won't resolve... very nice!

Answer (score 18):

`URI` has an old-fashioned idea of what an url looks like.

[Lately I'm using `addressable`](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2013/06/replace-rubys-uri-parser-with.html) to get around that:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'addressable/uri'

class URI::Parser
  def split url
    a = Addressable::URI::parse url
    [a.scheme, a.userinfo, a.host, a.port, nil, a.path, nil, a.query, a.fragment]
  end
end

resp = open("http://sub_domain.domain.com") # Yay!
```

Don't forget to `gem install addressable`

Comment: ```Addressable::URI``` follows the RFC more closely than ruby core's URI

Answer (score 14):

This initializer in my rails app seems to make URI.parse work at least:

```rb
# config/initializers/uri_underscore.rb
class URI::Generic
  def initialize_with_registry_check(scheme,
                 userinfo, host, port, registry,
                 path, opaque,
                 query,
                 fragment,
                 parser = DEFAULT_PARSER,
                 arg_check = false)
    if %w(http https).include?(scheme) && host.nil? && registry =~ /_/
      initialize_without_registry_check(scheme, userinfo, registry, port, nil, path, opaque, query, fragment, parser, arg_check)
    else
      initialize_without_registry_check(scheme, userinfo, host, port, registry, path, opaque, query, fragment, parser, arg_check)
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain :initialize, :registry_check
end
```

Comment: If you are using Rails, this is the best solution.  Thanks @cluesque

Answer (score 6):

Here is a patch that solves the problem for a wide variety of situations (rest-client, open-uri, etc.) without using external gems or overriding parts of URI.parse:

```
module URI
  DEFAULT_PARSER = Parser.new(:HOSTNAME => "(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\\d](?:[-\\_a-zA-Z\\d]*[a-zA-Z\\d])?)\\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[-\\_a-zA-Z\\d]*[a-zA-Z\\d])?)\\.?")
end
```

Source: [lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb#L86](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/202bbda2bf5f25343e286099140fb9282880ecba/lib/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb#L86)

Ruby-core has an open issue: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8241

Comment: This one works great. But it gives a warning because of constant 
    DEFAULT_PARSER already existing. To prevent this I used:

    module URI
      original_verbose, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, nil
      DEFAULT_PARSER = Parser.new(:HOSTNAME => "(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\\d](?:[-\\_a-zA-Z\\d]*[a-zA-Z\\d])?)\\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[-\\_a-zA-Z\\d]*[a-zA-Z\\d])?)\\.?")
      $VERBOSE = original_verbose
    end`

Comment: This also solved my issue when using URI.extract and it was breaking on links with underscores in the subdomain.

Answer (score 3):

An underscore can not be contained in a domain name like that. That is part of the DNS standard. Did you mean to use a dash(`-`)?

Even if open-uri didn't throw an error such a command would be pointless. Why? Because there is no way it can resolve such a domain name. At best you'd get an `unknown host` error. There is no way for you to register a domain name with an `_` in it, and even running your own private DNS server, it is against the specification to use a `_`. You could bend the rules and allow it(by modifying the DNS server software), but then your operating system's DNS resolver won't support it, neither will your router's DNS software.

Solution: Don't try to use a `_` in a DNS name. It won't work anywhere and it's against the specifications

Comment: no, I meant exactly underscores. As I mentioned, I understand that it is not allowed by standards, but there are URLs like that (for instance on livejournal.com) and I have to deal with them.

Comment: @Arty ahh, I hadn't realized such a big player as livejournal would allow such RFC breakage. Welp, I don't know then :P

Comment: Per [RFC 3986 section 2.3](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), underscore is not a reserved character. It is unreserved.

Comment: It's not just livejournal that does it, Windows allows underscores in machine names, and that way you can end up with a broken hostname having an underscore. It's true as Tin Man says that underscores are allowed in the hostname part of a generic URI since they're unreserved characters, but that doesn't contradict what Earlz says, that you can't (successfully) use such hostnames with DNS. The fact that it's allowed in a URI doesn't imply it'll actually resolve, presumably this is justified since registered domains and resolvable hosts are not the only possible uses of URIs.

Comment: These URLs will resolve, for example http://test_underscore.stackednotion.com/ will take you to my website. That still doesn't get around that it isn't a valid URL, so shouldn't be used though :)

Comment: **Subdomains are allowed to have underscores.** http://stackoverflow.com/a/2183140/203130

Comment: Amazon S3 buckets are also allowed to have underscores, and do create domain names.  This means even more domains you'd like to access using ruby, URI, and OpenURI

Comment: I beg to differ. Underscores work in subdomains just fine, in all cases I have encountered, as demonstrated by a great many S3 buckets. The spec may not allow it, but that's a different matter.

Comment: RFC 2181 clarified some parts of the DNS spec and says a label may be any valid binary string. It also says that applications can have more constraints. Looking through RFC 3986, I read it as saying the hostname portion of the URI is valid if you can pass it do the DNS system.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another ugly hack, no gem needed:

```
def parse(url = nil)
    begin
        URI.parse(url)
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
        host = url.match(".+\:\/\/([^\/]+)")[1]
        uri = URI.parse(url.sub(host, 'dummy-host'))
        uri.instance_variable_set('@host', host)
        uri
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error while trying to use gem update / gem install etc. so I used the IP address instead and its fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Curb gem: https://github.com/taf2/curb which just wraps libcurl.  Here is a simple example that will automatically follow redirects and print the response code and response body:

```
rsp = Curl::Easy.http_get(url){|curl| curl.follow_location = true; curl.max_redirects=10;}
puts rsp.response_code
puts rsp.body_str
```

I usually avoid the ruby URI classes since they are too strick to the spec which as you know the web is the wild west :)  Curl / curb handles every url I throw at it like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this:

Ruby's `URI.parse` used to be based on RFC2396 (published in Aug 1998), see https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8241

But starting at ruby 2.2 URI is [upgraded into RFC 3986](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS), so if you're on a modern version, no monkey patches are necessary now.

Comment: You are not wrong that URI supports RFC3986 parsing, but the default parser as of Ruby 3.0 and all prior versions is still `RFC2396` as you can see here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_0_3/lib/uri/common.rb#L17