# Zend HTTP Client Invalid URI?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-http-client

I'm having trouble using Zend HTTP on a URL:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://xxfire_killumiex.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/info.json');
$feed = $client->request()->getBody();
```

For some reason, this gives me an error...

```
Invalid URI supplied
```

Whats wrong this this specific url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whats wrong this this specific url?

The underscore.

From RFC 1912

> Allowable characters in a label for a host name are only ASCII
>      letters, digits, and the `-' character.

**Edit**

After doing some more reading, it seems that Zend may be wrong in this case.

See [Can (domain name) subdomains have an underscore "_" in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180465/can-someone-have-a-subdomain-with-an-underscore-in-it/2183140#2183140)

According to [ZF-9671](http://www.zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-9671), you might be out of luck, though I've re-opened the issue.

My suggestion in the meantime; Create your own HTTP client class like this

```
class My_Http_Client extends Zend_Http_Client
{
    public function validateHost($host = null)
    {
        if ($host === null) {
            $host = $this->_host;
        }

        // If the host is empty, then it is considered invalid
        if (strlen($host) === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran a str_replace to replace it with %5F, it didn't make a difference. Underscores are valid URI characters anyways, so why would it be an issue?

Comment: @Jason here is a regex that ZF uses to validate URI `preg_match('/^[0-9.a-e:.]*$/i', $value)`

Comment: I can replace it with %5F, I can run rawurlencode() on it... doesn't make a difference... still gives the same error.

Comment: @criticus That's the IP address schema validation. The hostname validation pattern found in `Zend_Validate_Hostname` is `/^[a-z0-9\x2d]{1,63}$/i`

Comment: @Jason You can replace it with whatever you want but unless it contains only letters, digits or hyphen, it will fail

Comment: umm... no. Thats not how Zend_Http_Client works... the following url works perfectly fine `http://xifcsxswx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/info.json`. If it could only have letters digits and hyphens, then you couldn't have slashes or periods. This is a URL, not a string.

Comment: @Jason Take note that I'm only referring to the **hostname** part. I've found some more information though and will add it to my answer