# handling Zend_Http_Client Invalid URI supplied

Tags: uri, zend-http-client

i have an error during run this simple code.

```
$hc = new Zend_Http_Client();
$hc->setUri('http://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/ایران');
// Invalid URI supplied
```

how can i handle the valid uri for zend http client?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318674/zend-http-client-invalid-uri

Comment: i want to the method or function to automatically handle uri.