# Target host must not be null, or set in parameters

Tags: android, android-manifest, http-post

I get this error "Target host must not be null, or set in parameters". My manifest file has internet permission set, and I have put 'http://' before my Url. It still gives the same error. My URL does not have a 'www.' attached to it.

Part of my Code:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://infocreation.something_something1.xml");
```

Part of my manifest is like below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET/>
```

What do I do now?

Comment: Just to be clear: there is no such thing as an ".xml" TLD, so either your example-URI above is badly chosen, or you are trying to do something strange. If your real code also has the `.xml`, then there's your problem: there is no such thing to send a HTTP request to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Using the URL without the underscore has worked for me. The .xml part is ok.

Comment: by the way, I was getting this error because I forgot to add http://.  I was writing www.something.com, but it must be http://www.something.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I replaced the URL, with almost the same URL, except without the underscore and that worked. I realized from further searches (for example [here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446578/using-openstream-with-a-url-that-has-a-subdomain-with-an-underscore-in-it-return) that URLs with _(underscore) are not valid, although that particular URL may work. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 10):

It should be

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.infocreation.something.xml");
```

Comment: The url is not www.infocreation.something.xml. It is http://infocreation.something.xml. There is no www. I get a "Host name may not be null" error when I put www in the Url

Comment: I just tried going to your site, it doesnt exist. What are you trying to do?

Comment: There is no .com?  I tried navigating to your site and it says the server cant be found. Are you sure you are doing this correctly?

Comment: The Url i have put there is not the actual Url. I am trying to send data to that Url via post.

Comment: Oh! Well it would help to have the real url.

Comment: With the code in my answer that format should be working, unless it is something with the site.

Answer (score 7):

Are you putting a real and working url inot the HttpPost constructor?

Anyway this is your solution:

If you have the following code failing:

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("www.host.com");
```

Then the error is pretty easy to solve:
The problem is that you have not added a protocol to the URL, so change it to:

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.host.com");
```

And then it will work as wanted.

Source: [h3x.no](http://h3x.no/2010/11/22/httpclient-target-host-must-not-be-null-or-set-in-parameters)

Comment: Thank you Nanne. I didn't put the real URL in the question. The real URL doesn't have a www. attached to it. And I am using POST, not GET. Thank you.

Comment: You error was not refered to HttpGet or HttpPost, it was general. The error was because you were not putting the http://www or your url was wrong formed.