# Android AsyncTask Syntax error

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am running a simple FTP server for android. In my application, I am trying to use an AsyncTask. Here is my code:

```
private class start extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... str) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
   }
}
```

I am getting a syntax error on token "..." and an error saying insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclerationStatement. I have looked at the following AsyncTask tutorials:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

and I have looked at other questions including:
[Error "Asynctask"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401630/error-asynctask)
And nobody seems to have encountered simmilar errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please post the stacktrace and relevant code. Why are you using AsyncTask if `doInBackGround()` is empty?

Comment: There is no stacktrace- this is a syntax error. And I left it empty to highlight the fact that even without and code other than what is shown above, I am getting an error on "..." on the DoInBackground line.

Answer (score 0):

A syntax error from your IDE rather than a stack trace, right? That syntax looks right unless those first two ellipses are in your code - the one in the method signature is fine; if that one's the problem, I suggest restarting the IDE; they get tripped up sometimes.

Comment: They are not- they represent other code of mine I didn't feel was necessary to include. Unfortunately, restarting the IDE didn't work.