# Fatal Exception AsyncTask #1 at doInBackground()

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, httpclient, futuretask

I am newbie on Android and I am developing an app that gets some information from a QR code and then connects a php page. However app crushes after it reads QR code and logCat gives a Fatal Exception AsyncTask #1 when I run it.

Here is the `doInBackground()` codes:

```
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    { 
        protected String doInBackground(String... args)
        {
            String tc= new String();
            tc= "3123";

            String no = new String();
            no = "3";

            /*String tcKimlik = "3123";
            String hatNo = "3";*/

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tc", tc));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no", no ));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params);

            try
            {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1)
                {

                    //qrCodeText.setText("DONE!");
                }
                else
                {
                    //qrCodeText.setText("Nope...");
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    } // End of CreateNewProduct
```

`CreateNewProduct` is in another class that reads QR codes and I call it like `new CreateNewProduct().execute();` after Qr code is read.

And here is LogCat:

UPDATE:

After I added `http://` and made `setTexT()` as comment, JSON error was added to LogCat:

```
05-16 01:00:08.900: E/JSON Parser(11835): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

05-16 01:00:08.900: W/dalvikvm(11835): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410572a0)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at com.example.yoritreader.MainActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:442)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at com.example.yoritreader.MainActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-16 01:00:08.910: E/AndroidRuntime(11835):    ... 5 more
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was solved removing `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` from php file.

Answer (score 1):

```
Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=www.halilcosgun.com/qrcode.php
```

You probably forgot to put the protocol in the URL of your site.

Try with http://www.halilcosgun.com/qrcode.php

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8768930/1296658

Comment: After I added "http://" and made "setText" as comment, it added 2 more lines to LogCat

Comment: `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`. Well you are not reading JSON from the php site so it is normal that it cannot be read on Android. You need to either parse the String you get yourself on the client or expose a JSON format string on the server.

Comment: I also use a class named `JSONParser` to get `JSONObject`. Could the error be in it?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to parse a String which does not contain JSON as JSON. Have a look at what JSON format looks like @ http://www.w3schools.com/json/ What you expose is a html site which cannot be parsed as with a JSON parser but you need to make a HTML parser yourself or find one online

Comment: Can solving JSON problem also solve the `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1` problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your current problem is that you need to add `"http://"` or the like to your `url` when you send the request. That should take care of your current problem, `IllegalStateException`. Your next problem is going to be trying to access `UI` elements from a background `Thread`. You need to move the lines where you call `setText()` to `onPostExecute()` or to an `Activity` method

Since you aren't allowed to access `UI` elements from the background this line

```
qrCodeText.setText("DONE!");
```

and any others where you try to update the `UI` will give you an error. You can `return success` to `onPostExecute()` and perform it that way since all other `AsyncTask` methods run on the `UI`. This is assuming they have access to these elements as in being an inner class of the `Activity` or passing a reference to them in your constructor

Comment: After I added "http://" and made "setText" as comment, it added 2 more lines to LogCat:

E/JSON Parser(11835): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

and

W/dalvikvm(11835): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410572a0)

Comment: Please don't change your OP...it will be confusing and useless for others. You can add to it if you are having an issue similar to your original issue. If it is a separate issue then you can accept an answer that helped with the original problem and post a new question

Comment: As you can see from LogCat FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 is still unsolved. Only error parsing data was added to LogCat and I cannot get an answer to solve the problems.

Comment: I understand that...adding extra logcat was fine. I just meant commenting out the `setText()` calls. I will try to look some more in a bit