# error occured while executing doInBackground

Tags: android, authentication

i'm new in android and i'am trying to make login system.... but it give me an error while i fill the edittexts with some values:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

This is my code:

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText user, pass;
private Button mSubmit;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
static{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


private static final String LOGIN_URL = "sorifgroupcom.ipage.com/Android/login.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MPLogin);

    mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnLogin);

    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.BtnLogin:
        new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("motdepasse", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            Log.i("tesssssssssssssssssssst", "test");
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                // save user data
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("email", username);
                edit.commit();
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("tesssssssssssssssssssst", "test");
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.cancel();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

}
```

And the logCat print :

```
01-08 00:14:23.345: E/Trace(1016): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing     doInBackground()
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=sorifgroupcom.ipage.com/Android/login.php
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at  org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)  
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:51)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:128)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-08 00:14:29.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     ... 5 more
01-08 00:14:31.865: E/BufferQueue(35): [org.Soufiane.voyagesociale/org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.Login] drainQueueLocked: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016): Activity org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4102a2e0 that was originally added here
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4102a2e0 that was originally added here
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:109)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.Login.onClick(Login.java:88)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-08 00:14:32.205: E/WindowManager(1016):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 00:16:32.855: E/ThrottleService(163): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException:   problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-08 00:26:32.896: E/ThrottleService(163): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the logcat:

> Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null,
>   host=null, path=sorifgroupcom.ipage.com/Android/login.php

it is taking everything as a path, without host. And thats because you didnt specify the scheme.

change

```
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "sorifgroupcom.ipage.com/Android/login.php";
```

to

```
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://sorifgroupcom.ipage.com/Android/login.php";
```

Comment: thanks Carlos i change that and it give another error
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Fatal of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: thats another problem, probably the results from that URL are not correctly formated. if you want, accept this answer and then create a new question , since you will have to provide with some different information (and give me the link of the question if you want)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000069/value-fatal-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the protocol for your URL. Use `http://` or `https://` when you set your `LOGIN_URL`

See here for more details: [Target host must not be null, or set in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759108/target-host-must-not-be-null-or-set-in-parameters)