# Error: Value Fatal of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, authentication

In Android, I want to implement a login system and I'm having an error in converting a `String` into a `JsonObject`. This is my Activity:

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {    
    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    static {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://sorifgroupcom.ipage.com/Android/login.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MPLogin);

        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnLogin);

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {    
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.BtnLogin:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;


        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("motdepasse", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            Log.i("tesssssssssssssssssssst", "test");
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                // save user data
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("email", username);
                edit.commit();
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("tesssssssssssssssssssst", "test");
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.cancel();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

And the LogCat prints the following errors when I put values into `TextEdit`:

```
E/JSON Parser(619): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: 
    Value Fatal of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AndroidRuntime(619): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(619): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured 
    while executing   doInBackground()

E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime(619): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at  org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:110)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
E/AndroidRuntime(619):  ... 5 more
E/InputDispatcher(163): channel '41868f48  org.Soufiane.voyagesociale/org.Soufiane.voyagesociale.Login (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be  disposed!
E/InputDispatcher(163): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.    fd=193, events=0x9
E/BufferQueue(35): [] drainQueueLocked: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
```

What does this error mean? And how can I fix this?

Comment: What is `Login.java` line 110.

Comment: Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is inside the `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest` function. 
Probably it is downloading a text from your server, that is not correctly formated.

You have to check what your "http://sorifgroupcom.ipage.com/Android/login.php" is returning.

Im making some request to that URL and i dont get any result (the response has an empty body)

Probably you have to check your php file to see what its returning. If you want, you can try a  POST request with [this online tool](http://www.requestmaker.com/) and post here the response body, or you can give me a valid username/password to set as parameters, to see what happens.

also, if you want, you can post the contents of the php file since i would bet money the error is there.  Probably your php file is not printing the json

Comment: you can try with email = hayatino@gmail.com, motdepasse = hatino

Comment: i find an error in my php file and it works great now, thank you Carlos i really appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question :-

```
java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Obviously you are trying to convert a string into json which is not possible by the way.
Look at your code again or debug it and tell the error on which the exception is coming.
Not just the line number, the code on that line too.

Secondly, you are using ASYNCTASK so don't write these lines :-

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

It is bad coding to use `StrictMode`

Comment: Strings representing JSON can be converted to JSONObject:  http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)

Comment: i use strict mode just for the erroe No such a file or directory
and line 110 is Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());