# HttpPost On android crashing app

Tags: android, mysql, http-post, httpclient

I'm trying to make an App to upload data from android to Mysql online.

It's simple, you fill 2 text entries, press the button and the HttpPost should happen. But it crashs my App.

I've made a simple PHP scrip to convert and now I'm trying to get android to send the data with HttpPost and HttpClient.

I've seen a lot of examples and came up with this code:

```
package com.lstupenengo.mysql;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void ClickBoton (View view){
        EditText ET1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_valor1);
        EditText ET2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_valor2);
        String valor1 = ET1.getText().toString();
        String valor2 = ET2.getText().toString();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("MY URL GOES HERE");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var", "SECRET"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var2", "SECRET"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("valor1", valor1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("valor2", valor2));
            //Random
            Random r = new Random();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("valor3", Integer.toString(r.nextInt(501))));


            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fallo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fallo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_valor1"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:hint="Valor 1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_valor2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/et_valor2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_valor2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_valor1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Valor2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enviar"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_valor2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/et_valor2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:onClick="ClickBoton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lstupenengo.mysql" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat

```
12-15 00:15:18.849  28334-28334/com.lstupenengo.mysql E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lstupenengo.mysql, PID: 28334
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3954)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18570)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3949)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18570)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=aprendiendo.zz.vc/sql.php
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.lstupenengo.mysql.MainActivity.ClickBoton(MainActivity.java:82)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3949)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18570)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The possible duplicate of this question is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759108/target-host-must-not-be-null-or-set-in-parameters

Comment: No, I've just read it. It seemed that the error in the other post was a bad URL. My URL is fine, I can browse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u r calling http post on button click , Http thread not run on main thread

Write an async task and do the network operation in that thread ,this thread runs in background

http://hmkcode.com/android-cleaner-http-asynctask/

and to study Async task

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html