# CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.6.5 with the setting:

```
DEBUG = True
```

When I change to `DEBUG = False` and run `manage.py runserver`, I get the following error:

```
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False
```

I get the same error with the following setting:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check if below you defined again DEBUG = True. It could be just a bad copypaste. I got here because I canceled DEBUG = False by accident

Comment: From the posts below, there isn't even one solution which resolves this...

Comment: I was having same error while original code's version was different from installed django version, I accidently changed django version in requirement.txt & this issue comes up, by adding same version django in requirement txt and installing again fixed the issue

Answer (score 252):

Try

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Less secure if you're not firewalled off or on a public LAN, but it's what I use and it works.

**EDIT:** Interestingly enough I've been needing to add this to a few of my 1.8 projects even when `DEBUG = True`. Very unsure why.

**EDIT:** This is due to a Django security update as mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Where should I put the code correctly, in order to not waste the code?

Comment: Do `grep ALLOWED_HOSTS . -ri` in your project's head folder to find the correct file. It's settings.py in this case, but grepping is always good advice.

Comment: in which file should I write this?

Comment: @MonaJalal please see Harald's comment.

Comment: I am on django 1.8 and this works (@monajalal settings.py)

Comment: According to [Django docs][1], the behavior of `ALLOWED_HOSTS` has been modified to address a DNS rebinding attack and this is probably necessary going forward.


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: From django documentation: In older versions, ALLOWED_HOSTS wasn’t checked if DEBUG=True. This was also changed in Django 1.9.11 and 1.8.16 to prevent a DNS rebinding attack.

Comment: It is worth commenting that Django does not even check ALLOWED_HOSTS when the host contains an underscore. More details in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218390/underscore-in-subdomain-label-valid-or-not

Comment: just what I was looking for. Django Version: 2.1.7, Python 3.6.7 working!

Comment: NOT found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Hi Getting this reply

Comment: @HamzaTahir this sounds like a separate issue.

Answer (score 81):

Your solution might be to add the original IP and/or hostname also:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
  'localhost',
  '127.0.0.1',
  '111.222.333.444',
  'mywebsite.example']
```

The condition to be satisfied is that the host header (or `X-Forwarded-Host` if `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` is enabled) should match one of the values in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

Comment: After configuring this, the good old restart worked for me...

Answer (score 33):

Make sure it's not redefined again lower down in your settings.py. The default settings has:

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = []`

Comment: The error msg leads one away from looking for this. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 17):

From documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/

> if DEBUG is False, you also need to properly set the ALLOWED_HOSTS
>   setting. Failing to do so will result in all requests being returned
>   as “Bad Request (400)”.

And from here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS

I am using something like this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'www.mysite.com']
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS =  ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you work in `PyCharm`, check the `Environmental variables` for your `Django server`. You should specify the proper `module.settings` file

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

Answer (score 2):

### If you are using PyCharm

**This solution applies only if you are using a different `settings.py` and have environment variables set**
I had the same issue, but in my case the issue was, I was using a different `settings.py` file than the default (and had commented out my whole original `settings.py`), though I had it properly configured in my `manage.py` but in **PyCharm** I had to configure it as well in my Environment Variables via:

```
Edit Run Configurations >> Environment Variables
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same error and found it is happening due to settings file configuration change. You have to configured few things as below mentioned.

Try

In settings.py

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

In manage.py

```
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<your-project-name>.settings')
```

In asgi.py

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<your-project-name>.settings')
```

In wsgi.py

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<your-project-name>.settings')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had split out my `settings.py` into `base.py` and `development.py` in a settings folder. It looked something like:

```
<name-of-your-project-app>/
├── __init__.py
├── asgi.py
├── settings
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base.py
│   └── development.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

The problem was much bigger than ALLOWED_HOSTS=... because none of the settings were recognized by `python manage.py runserver`.

The fix was to configure the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE by running

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=decoupled_dj.settings.development`

in the command line. I think this tells Django, 'Hey look for my settings in the `development.py`'

Answer (score 1):

So in my main directory in my django project, I had a two directories that had the same name so I deleted the settings folder I had and kept the settings.py file that comes with django.

**What I had originally**

```
<name-of-your-project-app>/
├── __init__.py
├── asgi.py
├── settings
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base.py
│   └── development.py
├── settings.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

**What I had afterwards**

```
<name-of-your-project-app>/
├── __init__.py
├── asgi.py
├── settings.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

A value of '*' will match anything; in this case you are responsible to provide your own validation of the Host header.

Answer (score 0):

I had set ALLOW_HOSTS, INTERNAL_IPS and DEBUG=TRUE

but still got this error.
my problem was i had created a python package which its name
was 'settings' in main app.
and that package name interfered with 'settings.py' file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name of the directory is the same that you are mentioning in the INSTALLED_APPS. These are the solution to errors sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error when using a .env file in development in a local setup on my computer which I didn't copy on the production server. As soon as I added the .env file on the production server the error was resolved. I have also added the server's IP Address to the *allowed_hosts* list on the settings file.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because settings.py does not recognized by Pycharm correctly. Therefore you must specify your settings.py file in Preferences.

Go to: **Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django ->**

1. `Enable Django Support`
2. Set `Django project root` to your main project folder
3. Set `Settings` to your `main_project/your_app/settings.py`
4. Set `Manage script` to your `main_folder/manage.py`

[image: Pycharm Django Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error appears out of nowhere, maybe after pulling latest code or after installing/configuring a new package, which is weird and none of the logical solutions shared work, I had this case.

In such cases, closely observe the recent code changes you have had especially in `settings.py`. Try these steps:

1. Try to comment-out latest changes in `settings.py`, mainly any new package/library that you configured, this may lead you to the package/library name which caused the problem.
2. Make sure that "every" environment variable that is being retrieved in `settings.py` is set in your env file, or you retrieve it with default value e.g. `env('API_KEY', default="abc")`.

In my case, one of my team member had configured [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/python_quickstart) in `settings.py`, after pulling latest code I got following changes:

```
cloudinary.config(
cloud_name=env("CLOUD_NAME"),
api_key=env("API_KEY"),
api_secret=env("API_SECRET"))
```

However, I did not have CLOUD_NAME, API_KEY, API_SECRET defined in my `.env` file. And this was the root problem for me(we are using [environ](https://pypi.org/project/django-environ/) for env vars).

SOLUTION: I just defined these env variables(CLOUD_NAME="", API_KEY="", API_SECRET="") in my environment variable file `.env` and it started working.

Answer (score -1):

I also experienced this cmderror. After trying all the answers on here, I couldn't still figure out the problem, here is what I did:

1. Cd into the project directory. e.g cd project-dir
2. I migrated. e.g python `manage.py` migrate
3. I created a super user. e.g python `manage.py` createsuperuser
4. Enter the desired info like username, password, email etc
5. You should get a "super user created successfully" response
6. Now run the server. E.g python `manage.py` runserver
7. Click on the URL displayed
8. The URL on your browser should look like this, `127.0.0.1:8000/Quit`
9. Now edit the URL on your browser to this, `127.0.0.1:8000/admin`
10. You should see an administrative login page
11. Login with the super user info you created earlier on
12. You should be logged in to the Django administration
13. Now click on "view site" at the top of the page
14. You should see a page which shows "the install worked successfully..... Debug = True"
15. Voila! your server is up and running

Answer (score -15):

Just simply comment out the line: ALLOWED_HOSTS = [...]

Comment: If comment, how will know where to redirect?