# app running on django dev server inaccessible from network computer

Tags: django

How do I access an app running on django dev server(ubuntu 15.10) from another machine on the same network(eg. a windows 7) ?
I am able to ping this machine from another network computer.

"python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" - does not allow me to access the app from another network computer.

app uses django 1.5.9

Comment: That is exactly what you do. What address are you putting in on the other computer? What do you see when you try?

Comment: can you try port 80?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver

> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from
>   other machines on your network. To make your development server
>   viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address
>   (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).

`runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Make sure you open port 8000

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

is ok but you have to also modify settings.py of your app. You need to change ALLOWED_HOSTS.
For example put * to allow access for everybody or put only certain IPs to limit access:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

more answers here:
[CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857158/commanderror-you-must-set-settings-allowed-hosts-if-debug-is-false)