# redirecting every url to 500 server error django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, whitenoise

my django application works in local development server. To deploy in heroku I had to use whitenoise for serving static files. The app is deployed successfully but now when I switch debug flag to False, i get server side error on both development and production server.

This is my confiugration

local_settings.py

```
from decouple import config
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)



import os
from decouple import config
import dj_database_url

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition
DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
]

OUR_APPS = [
    'inventory',
]


INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + OUR_APPS

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'IMS.urls'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_collected")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('inventory.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

handler404 = 'IMS.views.page_not_found'
handler500 = 'IMS.views.server_error'

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is the configuration in detail

https://gist.github.com/MilanRgm/166cf9aea3f401a4afec2d34c6511ed9

What have i missed or did wrong?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: No logs is shown in the console. https://ims-nepal.herokuapp.com/dashboard you can see this

Comment: Add yourself to [`ADMINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/error-reporting/) so you can get email reports of the error (and future errors).

Comment: Or else add plugin named "LogEntries" to your heroku admin dashboard for getting the error log details.

Comment: Is this line: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'], in settings.py?

Comment: yes it is. I am trying to use ADMINS in settings.py but I am not getting any mail. Do I have to configure SMTP myself?

Comment: I solved the problem for my case after trying lots of things, I don't remember exactly what was the issue couple things to try: Set ALLOWED_HOSTS to specific urls. In my case: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '.herokuapp.com', '.ngrok.io',]`. My settings has `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),)` different than yours. Maybe you'd like to try out these (IDK if these are going to solve the problem, deployment is a bit aweful :S )

Comment: The problem is shown in static files. Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'css/vendors/bootstrap.min.css' . But when i do http://localhost:8000/static/css/vendors/bootstrap.min.css the css code is shown

Comment: Could you please run `python manage.py collectstatic` to overload all the css and js files.

Comment: Also, did you add **DATABASE_URL** env variable in heroku settings?

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal it is solved. When i did the collectstatic, the missing css error was solved and also there was css dependency problem which is solved now. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in AWS.  This normally happens to me when my settings.py doesn't include:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Probably similar to [other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857158/commanderror-you-must-set-settings-allowed-hosts-if-debug-is-false)

Comment: You can see in my question. I have that included as well.

Comment: So local_settings.py is the same as your settings.py? I wasn't sure if you had two different settings files.

Comment: local_settings.py was made for having confidential data. The settings file i need to configure properly . Right now its a mess.