# Unable to run Django server

Tags: django

I'm trying to launch my Django server with the command `python manage.py runserver` but I got this error:

> CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.

Here is my settings project configuration:

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

Unlike other questions, my debug variable is set to True not False.

I've tried all the solutions proposed by others on the relative question with mine but the difference is that I've not changed the settings variable `Debug` so their solution doesn’t work for me.

I’ve changed the value of settings variable `ALLOWED_HOSTS` but it's not working for me.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857158/commanderror-you-must-set-settings-allowed-hosts-if-debug-is-false. Check the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED\_HOSTS if DEBUG is False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857158/commanderror-you-must-set-settings-allowed-hosts-if-debug-is-false)

Comment: it's not the same cause but i get the same as him mine the 'DEBUG' variable was set to 'True' but not for him so i don't need to change the value of 'ALLOWED_HOSTS'