# Validate URLs via Regex?

Tags: regex, validation

I have the following Regex

```
"^http\\\\://[a-zA-Z0-9\\\\-\\\\.]+\\\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\\\\S*)?$";
```

But I'm not sure that it's validating URLs correctly. Is anyone able to assist me or see what's wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: What paradigm are you using it? A lot of frameworks have this functionality built in.

Comment: Using in within ASP.NET MVC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, there a quite a bit of escapes "/" in your version

```
var subUrlSTR = "http://subdomain.stackoverflow.com";
var urlSTR = "http://stackoverflow.com";
var result = /http:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\.-]{3,}\.[A-Za-z]{3}/;
console.log(subUrlSTR.match(result));
console.log(urlSTR.match(result));
```

See it [working here](http://jsfiddle.net/srakesh/VD4YG/3/)

Comment: thanks a lot :) I do only want to match http://*.example.com where * can be any valid ? So i.e. http://www.example.com or http://blog.example.com ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a solid pattern [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url).

Looks like Rakesh some good mods to your existing pattern; however, if I were you I would consider the aforementioned patterns because they are a bit more robust depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Uri.TryCreate(stringUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### International & Modern Answer for 2023 And Beyond

Covering 99%+ URLs supported by modern browsers, that includes:

- [emojis  in domain name and path](http://factmyth.com/factoids/you-%F0%9F%91%8F-can-%F0%9F%91%8F-put-%F0%9F%91%8F-emojis-%F0%9F%91%8F-in-%F0%9F%91%8F-urls-%F0%9F%91%8F/)
- enforcing for top level domain: [first character should be alpha but can have numbers afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53875771/7333766), [2 characters minimum](https://www.quora.com/Will-there-be-a-single-letter-TLD-such-as-a-or-b-in-the-future-Why-didnt-ICANN-allow-such-TLDs-from-the-beginning), up to [the theoretical limit of 63](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238640/how-long-can-a-tld-possibly-be), yet allowing [underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180465/can-domain-name-subdomains-have-an-underscore-in-it), [accented characters](https://www.cira.ca/ca-domains/register-your-ca-domain/domains-french-accented-characters) and [internationalized characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Internationalized_generic_top-level_domains)
- [world's most common languages alphabets, characters & diacritics](https://www.berlitz.com/blog/most-spoken-languages-world) in path & domain name. Includes English (duh), French, Spanish, Portuguese, German, Italian, Bengali, Devenagri, Marathi, ~99% Chinese (CJK), Japanese, Korean, Taiwanese, Vietnamese, Urdu, Arabic, Greek, Cyrillic **and all others that share their character sets with these**
- Added versions with and without support for IPv4 URLs that are also used and seen online & supported by all modern browsers

##### Use this to include the protocol ("http/https") & IPv4 URLs:

```
https?:\/\/(\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):\d{1,5}\b|([-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})\.([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff()-]{1,62}))\b([\/#][-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff\u0900-\u097F\u0600-\u06FF\u0985-\u0994\u0995-\u09a7\u09a8-\u09ce\u0981\u0982\u0983\u09e6-\u09ef\u0750-\u077F\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\u4E00-\u9FFFẸɓɗẹỊỌịọṢỤṣụ()@:%_\+.~#?&//=\[\]!\$'*+,;]*)?
```

###### Use this to include the protocol but not IPv4 addresses:

```
https?:\/\/([-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})\.([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff()-]{1,62})\b([\/#][-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff\u0900-\u097F\u0600-\u06FF\u0985-\u0994\u0995-\u09a7\u09a8-\u09ce\u0981\u0982\u0983\u09e6-\u09ef\u0750-\u077F\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\u4E00-\u9FFFẸɓɗẹỊỌịọṢỤṣụ()@:%_\+.~#?&//=\[\]!\$'*+,;]*)?
```

###### To match domain names and paths (no IPv4):

```
([-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})\.([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff()-]{1,62})\b([\/#][-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff\u0900-\u097F\u0600-\u06FF\u0985-\u0994\u0995-\u09a7\u09a8-\u09ce\u0981\u0982\u0983\u09e6-\u09ef\u0750-\u077F\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\u4E00-\u9FFFẸɓɗẹỊỌịọṢỤṣụ()@:%_\+.~#?&//=\[\]!\$'*+,;]*)?
```

#### Battle-Tested with all these Real-World & Theoretical Edge Cases:

```js
// Check with a simple copy/paste in console!

const regexURLsAndIPs =
  /^https?:\/\/(\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):\d{1,5}\b|([-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})\.([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff()-]{1,62}))\b([\/#][-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u024F\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff\u0400-\u04ff\u0900-\u097F\u0600-\u06FF\u0985-\u0994\u0995-\u09a7\u09a8-\u09ce\u0981\u0982\u0983\u09e6-\u09ef\u0750-\u077F\uFB50-\uFDFF\uFE70-\uFEFF\u4E00-\u9FFFẸɓɗẹỊỌịọṢỤṣụ()@:%_\+.~#?&//=\[\]!\$'*+,;]*)?$/

const shouldMatch = [
  'https://base.com/',
  'http://t.co',
  'https://www.google.com.ua/',
  'https://subdomains.as.deep.as.you.want.example.com',
  'https://sub.second_leveldomain_underscore.verylongtoplevedomain/nice',
  'https://domain-name.com/path-common-characters/ABCxyz01789',
  'http://domaîn-with-àccents.ca',
  'http://path-with-accents.com/àèìòùçÇßØøÅåÆæœ',
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_strip',
  'http://www..tld/emojis--in--domain/-and-path-/',
  'https://y.at/',
  'https://hashtag.forpath#lets-go',
  "http://special.com/all-special-characters-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=",
  'https://greek_with_diacritics.co/ΑαΒβΣσ/ςΤτϋΰήώΊΪΌΆΈΎΫΉΏᾶἀ',
  'https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ποσειδώνας_(πλανήτης)',
  'http://cyrillic-and-extras.ru/АаБбВвЪъыӸӹЫЯЯяѶѷ',
  'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавная_страница',
  'https://most-arabic.co/گچپژیلفقهموء-يجريبتج/',
  'https://urdu.co/حروفِ/',
  'https://nigerian.ni/ƁƊƎẸɓɗǝẹỊƘỌịƙọṢỤṣụ',
  'https://bengali.sports.co/স্পর্শঅনুনাসিকলসওষ্ঠ্যপফবভম/',
  'https://devenagri.cc/कखगघङचछजझञटठडढणतथदधनपफबभमयरलवशषस',
  'https://h.org/wiki/Wikipedia:关于中文维基百科/en',
  'https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:关于中文维基百科/en',
  'http://others.kr/korean-안녕ㆅㅇㄹㅿㆍㅡㅣㅗㅑㅠㅕ/japanese-一龠ぁゔａｚＡＺ０９々〆〤ヶ',
  'https://龠.subdomain.com',
  'http://127.0.0.1:22/valid-ip',
  'http://127.00.00.01:22/ugly-but-still-works-with-modern-browsers',
  'http://0.0.0.0:0/is-min',
  'https://255.255.255.255:0/is-max',
  'https://this.tld-is-63-characters-wich-is-the-theoretical-limit-000000000000',
]

const shouldNotMatch = [
  'noprotocol.com',
  ' https://space-in-front.com',
  'https://invalid.0om',
  'https://invalid.-om',
  'https://invalid-single-letter-tld.c',
  'https://invalid-domain&char.com',
  'https://invalid:com',
  'https://not valid.com',
  'https://not,valid.com',
  'https://龠.c龠',
  'https://invalidαΒβΣσ.com',
  'notvalid://www.google.com',
  'http://missing-tld',
  'https://0.0.0.0missing-port',
  '0.0.0.0:0/missing-protocol',
  'https://256.255.255.255:0/is-above-max',
  'https://this.tld-is-64-characters-which-is-too-looooooooooooooooooooooooooong',
]

function checkStringsMatchRegex(regex, array, shouldMatch = true) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (regex.test(array[i]) !== shouldMatch) {
      const matchStr = shouldMatch ? 'match' : 'not match'
      console.error('regex.test(array[i])', regex.test(array[i]))
      throw new Error(`String "${array[i]}" should ${matchStr} regex "${regex}"`)
    }
  }
  const successMatchingStr = shouldMatch ? 'matching all strings' : 'not matching a single string'
  console.log(`Success with ${successMatchingStr} in the test array.`)
}

checkStringsMatchRegex(regexURLsAndIPs, shouldMatch, true)
checkStringsMatchRegex(regexURLsAndIPs, shouldNotMatch, false)
```