# Number in the top-level domain?

Tags: php, validation, dns

Can top-level domains contain a number at the end? Idk nothing about DNS rules etc but when I try to use PHP's filter_var() function with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL for `test@null.com1` it returns true.

Comment: I don't see a problem with such a tld (technically). `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` is just a basic test.

Comment: No email validation is a substitute for email verification, so whilst validation is a handy tool to weed out obvious mistakes and reduce the number of bad requests, it's probably not worth worrying about additional possible errors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Conceptually, there is nothing that disallows numbers in a [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) and in the future, who knows, perhaps there will be numeric TLDs.

There are no TLDs at the moment that do have numbers in them - the function probably does not test against a list of known TLDs (as it is subject to change), but lexically.

Comment: Well, that is interesting. Never looked on that matter. Just want to be sure that receiving statement is true for real. Thanks

Comment: actually there are, `xn--wgbh1c` is a TLD currently in use.. there are a few others too: http://www.swcs.com.au/tld.htm

Comment: @Oded, The bulk of your answer lies with the first paragraph, so what do you mean by "***Conceptually***"? (Also, tlds could not consist *entirely* of numbers, per https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/global-support/faqs/faqs-en "*an application for a string composed entirely of numbers will be rejected*")

Comment: @Pacerier - so, things can never change?

Comment: @Oded, I mean, does "***Conceptually***" refer to an RFC or something?

Comment: @Pacerier - no, it means that it is possible, some day in the future, that a new RFC will come that will allow it. It isn't likely, but it is, conceptually, a possibility.

Comment: "in the future, who knows, perhaps there will be numeric TLDs." Not possible under current rules, per RFC3696 section 2 (February 2004), all-numeric TLD is not allowed. This is also a rule enforced by ICANN. It allows any system to clearly disambiguate between hostnames and IP address, because otherwise `192.0.1.42` could as well be a subname of domain name `1` under TLD `42` (and there was in the past an experiment about the TLD .42 but done outside ICANN premises. It works then if domain names are never all numerical)

Answer (score 46):

> Does top-level domain can contain a number at the end?

Yes technically, except if it is purely numerical, then it can not be a TLD, under current rules and for easy reasons to understand (to disambiguate with IP addresses). And it can not contain a number at the end, except if it is an IDN TLD, for reasons enforced by ICANN.

Let us go back to some RFCs to have some clearer definitions of things:

## RFC 952: DOD INTERNET HOST TABLE SPECIFICATION (October 1985)

This is the definition of an Internet "hostname" back then:

> A "name" (Net, Host, Gateway, or Domain name) is a text string up
>   to 24 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus
>   sign (-), and period (.).  Note that periods are only allowed when
>   they serve to delimit components of "domain style names". (See
>   RFC-921, "Domain Name System Implementation Schedule", for
>   background).  No blank or space characters are permitted as part of a 
>   name. No distinction is made between upper and lower case.  The first 
>   character must be an alpha character.  The last character must not be 
>   a minus sign or period.

Note that this also has the following:

> Single character names
>      or nicknames are not allowed.

Hence at that point:

- `com1` is a valid TLD
- `3com` is not ("The first character must be an alpha character.")
- `42` is not (same reason)
- `1` is not (same reason)
- `a` is not ("Single character names or nicknames are not allowed.")

## RFC 1034: DOMAIN NAMES - CONCEPTS AND FACILITIES (November 1987)

This is one of the RFC that created the DNS as we know today. For compatibility reasons it defined hostnames as a sequence of labels, where a label is defined as such:

> They must start with a letter, end with a letter or digit, and have as
>   interior characters only letters, digits, and hyphen.  There are also
>   some restrictions on the length.  Labels must be 63 characters or
>   less.

The TLD is one label among others (the L in TLD). Per the above rule, `com1` is a valid label, and hence a valid TLD, where `3com` would not have been. Which directly brings us to the following amendment.

## RFC 1123: Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Application and Support (October 1989)

This amends the previous RFC by changing one rule:

> The syntax of a legal Internet host name was specified in RFC-952
>             [DNS:4].  One aspect of host name syntax is hereby changed: the
>             restriction on the first character is relaxed to allow either a
>             letter or a digit.  Host software MUST support this more liberal
>             syntax.

So at that point:

- `com1` is a valid TLD
- `3com` is also valid
- `42` is valid
- `1` is valid
- `a` is valid

For the case of "numerical" TLDs, the following rule in first document applies:

> Whenever a user inputs the identity of an Internet host, it SHOULD
>         be possible to enter either (1) a host domain name or (2) an IP
>         address in dotted-decimal ("#.#.#.#") form.  The host SHOULD check
>         the string syntactically for a dotted-decimal number before
>         looking it up in the Domain Name System.

and

> If a dotted-decimal number can be entered without such
>              identifying delimiters, then a full syntactic check must be
>              made, because a segment of a host domain name is now allowed
>              to begin with a digit and could legally be entirely numeric
>              (see Section 6.1.2.4).  However, a valid host name can never
>              have the dotted-decimal form #.#.#.#, since at least the
>              highest-level component label will be alphabetic.

## RFC 1738: Uniform Resource Locators (URL) (December 1994)

This also speaks about the TLD, but giving:

> The fully qualified domain name of a network host, or its IP
>           address as a set of four decimal digit groups separated by
>           ".". Fully qualified domain names take the form as described
>           in Section 3.5 of RFC 1034 [13] and Section 2.1 of RFC 1123
>           [5]: a sequence of domain labels separated by ".", each domain
>           label starting and ending with an alphanumerical character and
>           possibly also containing "-" characters. The rightmost domain
>           label will never start with a digit, though, which
>           syntactically distinguishes all domain names from the IP
>           addresses.

## RFC 3696: Application Techniques for Checking and Transformation of Names (February 2004)

This was needed to introduce IDNs (Internationalized Domain Names) and it has this to say:

> Any characters, or combination of bits (as octets), are permitted in
>      DNS names.  However, there is a preferred form that is required by
>      most applications.  This preferred form has been the only one
>      permitted in the names of top-level domains, or TLDs.  In general, it
>      is also the only form permitted in most second-level names registered
>      in TLDs, although some names that are normally not seen by users obey
>      other rules.  It derives from the original ARPANET rules for the
>      naming of hosts (i.e., the "hostname" rule) and is perhaps better
>      described as the "LDH rule", after the characters that it permits.
>      The LDH rule, as updated, provides that the labels (words or strings
>      separated by periods) that make up a domain name must consist of only
>      the ASCII [ASCII] alphabetic and numeric characters, plus the hyphen.
>      No other symbols or punctuation characters are permitted, nor is
>      blank space.  If the hyphen is used, it is not permitted to appear at
>      either the beginning or end of a label.  There is an additional rule
>      that essentially requires that top-level domain names not be all-
>      numeric.

In fact as soon as IDNs are involved, and they are IDN TLDs (both ccTLDs and gTLDs now), the encoding chosen generates an ASCII string of the form `xn--something` where the something can have digits, including at the end, like shown in other answers.

However it is not really clear from where the "additional rule" in the last sentence comes from.

## RFC 4697: Observed DNS Resolution Misbehavior (October 2006)

Not defining anything, but providing some interesting facts:

> The root name servers receive a significant number of A record
>      queries where the QNAME looks like an IPv4 address.

and

> A possible solution is to delegate these numeric TLDs
>      from the root zone to a separate set of servers to absorb the
>      traffic.

Which clearly shows that indeed, in the wild, there are applications, maybe by mistake but it shows at least that it works technically, sending queries for names that are indeed formatted like IPv4 addresses, so with a fully numerical "TLD".

There was in fact an experience to launch a `.42` registry, obviously completely outside of ICANN ecosystem. You can see a summary of it at http://www.dotsauce.com/experimental-numeric-tld-42-domain/ and an archive of their main explanations at https://web.archive.org/web/20101222151118/http://register.42registry.org:80/ (in French).

It did not went far, even if it technically works.

It showed for example that Microsoft based OS by default did not consider purely numeric TLDs at all, but they provided a patch for that: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947228/error-message-when-you-try-to-join-a-windows-vista-based-client-comput "When you try to join a Windows Vista-based client computer to a top level domain (TLD) that has a purely numeric suffix, the Windows Vista-based client computer cannot join the domain. [..]  This behavior is by design."

## Internet-Draft draft-liman-tld-names-06: Top Level Domain Name Specification (November 2011)

This finally gives some explanations on why purely numeric TLD or even TLD with one digit are sometimes considered invalid when it is not a clear consequence from above specifications:

(section 2.1 below refers to content in RFC 1123, quoted above)

> In addition, the DISCUSSION section of Section 2.1 says:
>
> ```
>  'However, a valid host name can never have the dotted-decimal form
>  #.#.#.#, since at least the highest-level component label will be
>  alphabetic.'  [Section 2.1]
> ```
>
> Some implementers may have understood the above phrase 'will be
>     alphabetic' to be a protocol restriction.

But it basically just recommend to go with the flow and continue the same restrictions:

> Neither [RFC0952] nor [RFC1123] explicitly states the reasons for
>      these restrictions.  It might be supposed that human factors were a
>      consideration; [RFC1123] appears to suggest that one of the reasons
>      was to prevent confusion between dotted-decimal IPv4 addresses and
>      host domain names.  In any case, it is reasonable to believe that the
>      restrictions have been assumed in some deployed software, and that
>      changes to the rules should be undertaken with caution.

Hence it offered this definition:

> traditional-tld-label = 1*63(ALPHA)

This draft never converted to an RFC because not everyone agreed with it. You can find a thread with dissenting voices for it at https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/dnsop/current/msg08866.html ; basically it was not clear if there was a restriction in the past that we are now trying to relax a little or if there never was a restriction to begin with and that people implemented systems wrongly.

For example you can see about this Chromium/Chrome bugreport: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31405
Browsing failed if using a TLD starting with a digit or purely numeric (it worked if it ended with a digit with letters before). This was not considered as a bug, and is not fixed, because the browser ships with a list of TLDs so it can know which ones are valid which are not, besides testing their syntax.

## ICANN Application Guidebook for new TLDs (June 2012)

Available at https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/agb/guidebook-full-04jun12-en.pdf
it says the following starting at page 64:

> The ASCII label (i.e., the label as transmitted on the wire) must be valid as specified in technical standards Domain Names: Implementation and Specification (RFC 1035), and Clarifications to the DNS Specification (RFC 2181) and any updates thereto.
>
> The ASCII label must be a valid host name, as specified in the technical standards DOD Internet Host Table Specification (RFC 952), Requirements for Internet Hosts — Application and Support (RFC 1123), and Application Techniques for Checking and Transformation of Names (RFC 3696), Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA)(RFCs 5890-5894), and any updates thereto. This includes the following:
>
> The ASCII label must consist entirely of letters (alphabetic characters a-z), or
>
> The label must be a valid IDNA A-label (further restricted as described in Part II below).

Specially note the: **The ASCII label must consist entirely of letters (alphabetic characters a-z)**

This immediately forbids any full numerical, as well as in fact any digit, including at end, except for IDN TLDs, the one with the form `xn--something`.

Note that someone asked directly ICANN about this, and got the following reply, shown at https://domaingang.com/domain-news/icann-applicant-handbook-this-is-why-we-cannot-have-numeric-gtlds/ :

> Please note Numeric TLD’s were prohibited in the first round of applications.
>      The prohibition on numeric gTLDs in the applicant guidebook (http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/agb) derives from a number of technical concerns regarding the ability of such domains to operate properly. Domain names are often used in place where other kinds of identifiers may be used like IP addresses.
>
> The fact that a TLD is all alphabetic is often a key determinant for software in identifying a domain name. If a TLD such as “.123” were allowed, you could have a domain name of “74.125.244.123” which would be difficult to discriminate from an IP address “74.125.244.123.”. There are also other considerations: some technical standards documentation states that TLDs will be alphabetical, which has been codified as an assumption in software also.
>
> The limitation in the AGB to alphabetic characters was designed to limit these scenarios that means such TLDs are not likely to work well in software, as well as limit potential security issues that may result from the same issues.

Comment: there is a very good reason that number cannot be a top level domain. It removes the possibility for a ambiguous addresses. for example:  if 42 was allowed as a top level domain, 0.42 could be a domain, 168.0.42 could be subdomain/2nd level domain, and 192.168.0.42 one level below.

Comment: "there is a very good reason that number cannot be a top level domain. It removes the possibility for a ambiguous addresses. " Which is not true. There was `.42` as TLD as an experiment, and it worked. Re-read the last paragraph above on the RFC1123 section.

Comment: "Which is not true". You gave practically the same answer (somewhat different address example) in the comments of the accepted answer. Can you explain why is my comment bad while yours is good? (I'm not trying to pick a fight, I'm genuinely interested in what I've missed)

Comment: `.42` existed as a TLD, even outside of IANA root. Your comment is "the rules are such because .42 can not be a TLD/would create mayhem if it was a TLD". I am just telling you your sentence is wrong based on facts, as .42 did exist as a TLD (a point I developed in my answer) and worked. Yes, it can create confusions (see last paragraph about RFC1123 above) but it does work. Is it useful, outside of a geeky exercise? Probably not. So today ICANN prohibits a TLD to be solely a number, yet technically it is possible.

Answer (score 20):

Actually there are quite a few TLDs currently in use that contain numbers:

> ```
> XN--1QQW23A
> XN--3BST00M
> XN--3DS443G
> XN--3E0B707E
> XN--45BRJ9C
> XN--4GBRIM
> XN--55QW42G
> XN--55QX5D
> XN--6FRZ82G
> XN--6QQ986B3XL
> XN--80ADXHKS
> XN--80AO21A
> XN--80ASEHDB
> XN--80ASWG
> XN--90A3AC
> XN--C1AVG
> XN--CG4BKI
> XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD
> XN--CZR694B
> XN--CZRU2D
> XN--D1ACJ3B
> XN--FIQ228C5HS
> XN--FIQ64B
> XN--FIQS8S
> XN--FIQZ9S
> XN--FPCRJ9C3D
> XN--FZC2C9E2C
> XN--GECRJ9C
> XN--H2BRJ9C
> XN--I1B6B1A6A2E
> XN--IO0A7I
> XN--J1AMH
> XN--J6W193G
> XN--KPRW13D
> XN--KPRY57D
> XN--KPUT3I
> XN--L1ACC
> XN--LGBBAT1AD8J
> XN--MGB9AWBF
> XN--MGBA3A4F16A
> XN--MGBAAM7A8H
> XN--MGBAB2BD
> XN--MGBAYH7GPA
> XN--MGBBH1A71E
> XN--MGBC0A9AZCG
> XN--MGBERP4A5D4AR
> XN--MGBX4CD0AB
> XN--NGBC5AZD
> XN--NQV7F
> XN--NQV7FS00EMA
> XN--O3CW4H
> XN--OGBPF8FL
> XN--P1AI
> XN--PGBS0DH
> XN--Q9JYB4C
> XN--RHQV96G
> XN--S9BRJ9C
> XN--SES554G
> XN--UNUP4Y
> XN--VHQUV
> XN--WGBH1C
> XN--WGBL6A
> XN--XHQ521B
> XN--XKC2AL3HYE2A
> XN--XKC2DL3A5EE0H
> XN--YFRO4I67O
> XN--YGBI2AMMX
> XN--ZFR164B
> ```

You can see an up to date list here [data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) or a list with descriptions here [swcs.com.au/tld.htm](http://swcs.com.au/tld.htm)