# Actionscript: check if string contains domain or subdomain

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, subdomain, match

I need to know if a string contains a specific domain

I have an array like this

```
private var validDomain:Array  =  new Array(
  "http://*.site1.com",
  "http://*.site2.com",
  "http://*.site3.com",
  );

private var isValidDomain:Boolean =  false; 
private var URL:string =  "http://mysub.site2.com";
```

now i would check if my string is valid, so i think something like that:

```
for each (var domain_ in validDomain){
      if(SOMEREGEX){
      isValidDomain=true;
      }
  }
```

What i put in SOMEREGEX?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you use two different logics.

The first one is a wildcard-based string, with wildcards like `*`; you must translate this wildcard based pattern in a regular expression pattern.

To accomplish this, a quick and dirty solution would be to do some string replacements like:

- substituting the `*` wildcard in the pattern with `.*`
- escaping the characters in the wildcard based pattern that are "special" to regular expressions (e.g. substituting `.` with `\.`

With this logic in mind, you will transform a wildcard based pattern like:

```
http://*.mydomain.com
```

into a regular expression pattern:

```
http:\/\/.*\.mydomain\.com
```

which you can use to test your string.

**edit**: `.*` is a very crude way to test for a subdomain, to do things neatly you should use a correct pattern like the ones in this thread: [Regexp for subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930751/regexp-for-subdomain)