# Validate format of subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, subdomain

How can I properly validate a subdomain format?

Here's what I've got:

```
  validates :subdomain, uniqueness: true, case_sensitive: false
  validates :subdomain, format: { with: /\A[A-Za-z0-9-]+\z/, message: "not a valid subdomain" }
  validates :subdomain, exclusion: { in: %w(support blog billing help api www host admin en ru pl ua us), message: "%{value} is reserved." }
  validates :subdomain, length: { maximum: 20 }
  before_validation :downcase_subdomain
  protected
    def downcase_subdomain
      self.subdomain.downcase! if attribute_present?("subdomain")
    end
```

Question:

Is there a standard REGEX subdomain validation like there is for email? What is the best REGEX for subdomain to use?

`validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }, allow_blank: true`

Comment: domains and subdomains can be numbers, texts or mixed but not characters like `%,$,^,&` etc...

Comment: Why not use `URI.parse()`?

Comment: @max if actual domain is invalid with ending `-`, how subdomain can be valid ? https://www.namecheap.com/domains/registration/results.aspx?domain=yaprak-.com

Comment: Can you give us an example of valid and invalid values?

Comment: I rephrased the question to clearify what I was looking for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) defines subdomain syntax like so:

```
<subdomain> ::= <label> | <subdomain> "." <label>

<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]

<ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>

<let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"

<let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>

<letter> ::= any one of the 52 alphabetic characters A through Z in
upper case and a through z in lower case

<digit> ::= any one of the ten digits 0 through 9
```

And a merciful human readable description.

> [Labels] must start with a letter, end with a letter or digit, and have as interior characters only letters, digits, and hyphen.  There are also some
> restrictions on the length. Labels must be 63 characters or less.

We can do most of this with a regex, and the length restriction separately.

```
validates :subdomain, format: {
  with: %r{\A[a-z](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\z}i, message: "not a valid subdomain"
}, length: { in: 1..63 }
```

Pulling that regex into pieces to explain it.

```
%r{
  \A
  [a-z]                       # must start with a letter
  (?:
    [a-z0-9-]*                # might contain alpha-numerics or a dash
    [a-z0-9]                  # must end with a letter or digit
  )?                          # that's all optional
 \z
}ix
```

We might be tempted to use the simpler `/\A[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]?\z/i` but this allows `foo-`.

See also [Regexp for subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930751/regexp-for-subdomain).

Comment: fantastic explanation and a special thank you for the regex explanation in the end!

Comment: @Yshmarov You're welcome. I'd just written something similar and this caused me to realized I had a bug, I'd forgotten about dashes. Domain validation comes up so often it's prompted me to work on [`validates_hostname`](https://github.com/KimNorgaard/validates_hostname) and see about adding a subdomain/label validator.