# Regex recursion captured string

Tags: regex, regex-group, capturing-group

I have a problem with a regex that has to capture a substring that it's already captured...

I have this regex:

`(?<domain>\w+\.\w+)($|\/|\.)`

And I want to capture every subdomain recursively. For example, in this string:

`test1.test2.abc.def`

This expression captures `test1.test2` and `abc.def` but I need to capture:
`test1.test2`
`test2.abc`
`abc.def`

Do you know if there is any option to do this recursively?

Thanks!

Comment: What regex flavor are you using? Some support recursive match.

Comment: So you're saying that it's possible a regex to make match text that does not belong to that text in the first place @Schwern?

Comment: Note that domain names include `-` and exclude `_`. `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` is a better approximation. See this answer for a proper regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269926/validate-format-of-subdomain/60271196#60271196

Comment: @Themelis I'm thinking [`(?R)`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) might be useful. Not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: `(?=(?<!\w)(\w+\.\w+)(?!\w))`

Comment: Have you had time to check my suggestion? Others' suggestions? Did anything work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a [well-known technique to extract overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp), but you can't rely on `\b` boundaries as they can match between a non-word / word char and word / non-word char. You need unambiguous word boundaries for left and right hand contexts.

Use

```
(?=(?<!\w)(?<domain>\w+\.\w+)(?!\w))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Dui2s/1). Details:

- `(?=` - a positive lookahead that enables testing each location in the string and capture the part of string to the right of it

  - `(?<!\w)` - a left-hand side word boundary
  - `(?<domain>\w+\.\w+)` - Group "domain": 1+ word chars, `.` and 1+ word chars
  - `(?!\w)` -  a right-hand side word boundary
- `)` - end of the outer lookahead.

Another approach is to use dots as word delimiters. Then use

```
(?=(?<![^.])(?<domain>[^.]+\.[^.]+)(?![^.]))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Dui2s/2). Adjust as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the [following](https://regex101.com/r/QcLNw6/4):

```
(\.|^)(?=(\w+\.\w+))
```

Go with capturing group 2

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use a positive look ahead to capture the next group.</strike>

```
/(\w+)\.(?=(\w+))/g
```

[Demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/ZPb58r/1).

Edit: [JvdV's regex is more correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60315059/14660).

---

Note that `\w+` is will fail to match domains like `regex-tester.com` and will match invalid `regex_tester.com`. `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` is closer to correct. [See this answer for a complete regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269926/validate-format-of-subdomain/60271196#60271196).

---

It's simpler and more robust to do this by splitting on `.` and iterating through the pieces in pairs. For example, in Ruby...

```
"test1.test2.abc.def".split(".").each_cons(2) { |a|
  puts a.join(".")
}

test1.test2
test2.abc
abc.def
```