# Regexp match domain and subdomain only from given domain in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

This is what I got so far I'm getting some status to fail;

https://regex101.com/r/KuUS5L/1

```
[[:<:]]lms.com[[:>:]]
```

These are my expected status:

| Keyword | status |
| --- | --- |
| lms.com | 1 |
| live.lms.com | 1 |
| live-lms.com | 0 |
| cssslms.com | 0 |
| lmsccc.com | 0 |
| lms.com.ph | 0 |
| lms.com.edu | 0 |

```
SELECT 
*
 FROM
(SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', - 1) AS substrEmail1,
    email
FROM
    members m1) AS d
 WHERE d.substrEmail1 regexp '[[:<:]]gs.com[[:>:]]';
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/o1zflx/1 or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49134699/460557 with a slight change to remove the dash

Comment: thanks @JorgeCampos i need this simplified to be used in a mysql query, i have updated the question above for details

Comment: Same thing for MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a51de/1

Comment: Or this variant which also works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a51de/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer, provided also in the comments.

Either:

```
select * from test
where url REGEXP '^([[:alpha:]]+\\.lms|lms)\\.com$' = 1;
```

Or

```
select * from test
where url REGEXP '^([[:alpha:]]+\\.)?lms\\.com$' = 1
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a51de/2