# Laravel Cashier fails to connect to Stripe in Homestead due to lack of local certificate path

Tags: ssl, laravel, openssl, stripe-payments

I set up Laravel Cashier and it fails to connect to Stripe.

I've isolated the bug to the point where this simple line fails:

```
$user = new User();
$user->subscription()->create('test');
```

The error is nondescript:

`Stripe_ApiConnectionError` in `vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php`

> Could not connect to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com). Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists, you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus. Reason was:

As you can see, `$errstr`, used to display the reason, is null.

### My research so far...

`$errstr` can be null because of [an unfixed PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65679) when the certificate check fails.

I found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584445/adding-a-new-ssl-certificate-to-solve-verify-return-code-20-unable-to-get-loca) which mentions that it's because the CAPath is not specified.

This indeed seems to be the case in Homestead / Vagrant. I suspect something is wrong in the default VagrantBox config.

When I run this command from my Mac I get a return code `0` (working):

```
openssl s_client -connect api.stripe.com:443
```

When I run the same command from Homestead I get a return code `20` (unable to get local issuer certificate):

To make it work in Homestead, I have to manually specify the `CAPath` like so:

```
openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect api.stripe.com:443
```

Then I get return code 0.

How can I fix this for good so my Cashier calls work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like running `vagrant provision` fixed the problem. Odd...

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, and running vagrant provision didn't help.

My Homestead box has a habit of the clock going slightly or sometimes very out of time. It seemed that **updating the time on Homestead to the correct time fixed it**. Perhaps this is why running the `provision` command fixed it in your case.

You can do this by running:

```
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
sudo service ntp start
```

---

As I had to do this relatively often (it also caused issues with [Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scout)) I ran:

```
php artisan make:command UpdateClock
```

and then edited `app/Console/Commands/UpdateClock.php` to the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class UpdateClock extends Command
{
    /** The name and signature of the console command. */
    protected $signature = 'clock:update';

    /** The console command description */
    protected $description = 'Updates vagrants clock';

    /** Create a new command instance */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /** Execute the console command. */
    public function handle()
    {
        exec("sudo service ntp stop");
        exec("sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov");
        exec("sudo service ntp start");
    }
}
```

Now whenever it goes out of time I just run:

```
php artisan clock:update
```