# SSL/TLS impact on postfix using default ca-bundle.crt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Recently you must have heard about AWS to Switch to SHA256 Hash Algorithm for SSL Certificates
We are using postfix integration with Amazon SES, I am using default CA certificate as mentioned in the Integrating Amazon SES with Postfix documentation [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html) I am using [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4f2b8f97f768940dbb7b) ca certificate,Can you please verify that this cert uses SHA256 algorithm so that I would not be affected by this SSL/TLS certificate changes

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this, you can verify your CA Certificate using the following command 
curl -k https://www.amazonsha256.com --cacert ca-bundle.crt

more info from aws [link](https://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/aws-to-switch-to-sha256-hash-algorithm-for-ssl-certificates/), Also have a look at this which shows using openssl how to verify ssl certs [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548336/openssl-verify-return-code-20-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)