# SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server hello A

Tags: ssl, certificate

I am having troubles with one of our test servers. For some reason when I run

```
openssl s_client -state -showcerts -connect stg.imotors.com:443
```

I get the following output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
write:errno=54
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1550027343
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

However, when I run the same on the actual server

```
openssl s_client -state -showcerts -connect www.imotors.com:443
```

It seems to be able to complete the entire handshake:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
---
Certificate chain
....

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA1
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4856 bytes and written 490 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    Session-ID: 003E000....
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: C8F818FA1F6DDF04CFCF08DA59B593D534DA....
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1550027379
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Both server are using the same wildcard certificate. Any ideas or suggestions how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Look here for several hints: [OpenSSL Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548336/openssl-verify-return-code-20-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: This solved the issue. I had to add -servername to the openssl command