# openssl certificate error for WinRM connection

Tags: linux, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, winrm

I have on Windows server certificate which is valid and active and WinRM listener is active as well on port 5986 (telnet works) for WinRM connection that needs to be established from the Linux server.

I didn't copy that certificate anywhere on the linux server as I do not know where that should be or how it should be configured.

If I try to establish WinRM connection I am getting this error on the Linux server.

```
openssl s_client -connect 10.7.147.210:5986      


No client certificate CA names sent

Peer signing digest: SHA256

Peer signature type: RSA

Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-384, 384 bits

---

SSL handshake has read 1367 bytes and written 447 bytes
```

Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate

I tried by referencing `CAfile` and `CApath` and `cert` option but without success:

```
 openssl s_client -cert winrmcert.pem -key winrmcert.key -CApath . -connect 10.7.147.210:5986

openssl s_client -CAfile winrmcert.pem  -connect 10.7.147.210:5986
```

Can you please help me what I need to do and configure on Linux server for certificate generated on Windows server for WinRM connection? I am not the expert for this topic so I would appreciate all useful instructions. Thank you

Comment: This isn't about programming or development. To use `-CApath .` you must have the server cert _only if_ selfsigned and otherwise the _root-CA_ cert in a file in the current directory _named using the (truncated) hash of the subject name_, as explained on the man page for verify (or in 3.0 for openssl-verification-options) -- do you? If instead you have an arbitrarily-named file (still with selfsigned or root only) use `-CAfile`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for your kind assistance. This is self signed certificate. I have used `-CAFile` option to reference `PEM` as well but the same error is returned.
`openssl s_client -CAfile winrmcert.pem  -connect 10.7.147.210:5986`

Issuer and Subject are having these values.
        `Issuer: CN = vwmazfasapp02.fisdev.local
            Not Before: Oct 22 16:41:35 2021 GMT
            Not After : Oct 22 16:51:34 2025 GMT
        Subject: CN = vwmazfasapp02.fisdev.local`

Comment: Could you please provide me additional advice? It has in Windows intended purposes: Client and Server Authentication. I tried to ask this question in UnixStackExchange but without success. I am really not sure what I should check additionally. Issued to and Issued by are both having the same value referencing my hostname value `vwmazfasapp02.fisdev.local`. I exported this certificate in PFX format in Windows and converted it to the PEM format in Linux. Thank you

Comment: `openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha1 -inform pem -in winrmcert.crt
SHA1 Fingerprint=4C:18:D2:EA:00:97:7B:D1:D1:4C:E6:C9:B0:B2:F5:6E:52:4E:8C:42`
thumberprint is the same like the certificate thumberprint on Windows
`Thumbprint   : 4C18D2EA00977BD1D14CE6C9B0B2F56E524E8C42
Subject      : CN=vwmazfasapp02.fisdev.local`

Comment: You can't use `winrmcert.pem` as your CAFile. The CAFile should point to a file containing the server CA or certificate if it is self-signed.