# Why can I not ping addresses with leading or trailing underscores on linux

Tags: linux, dns, ping

On windows:

- Accessing `_.github.com` in the browser works
- `nslookup _.github.com` works
- `ping _.github.com` works

On linux (tested on two separate networks):

- Accessing `_.github.com` in the browser works
- `host _.github.com` works
- `ping _.github.com` **does not**
- `python -c "import requests; requests.get('_.github.com')"` **does not**

What is going on here?

Comment: This also happends with `a_.github.com`, `_a.github.com`, but `a_a.github.com` works normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Linux (more specifically, some component of it such as libresolv or even ping itself) is honoring the RFCs. Underscores are not allowed in hostnames, and a hostname is what you are looking up when using ping. (Underscores are allowed in other types of DNS records, for example SRV records, TXT records such as those used for DKIM...)

See [RFC 1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt) section 2.1, and [RFC 952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc952.txt). Here are some other links to discussion of this topic:

[Stack Overflow - Can (hostname) subdomains have an underscore “_” in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2180465/2449905)

[Domainkey - Underscores in DNS](http://domainkeys.sourceforge.net/underscore.html)

[Quora - Why are underscores not allowed in DNS host names?](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-underscores-not-allowed-in-DNS-host-names)

**Update**: As a couple of people pointed out in comments, Linux ping is happy with `a_a.github.com`. Doing a few more tests (CentOS 7 in this case):

```
ping: unknown host _.github.com
ping: unknown host a_.github.com
ping: unknown host _a.github.com

$ ping a_a.github.com
PING github.map.fastly.net (23.235.40.133) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 23.235.40.133: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=29.7 ms
```

So it seems Linux ping does not reject the underscore completely, but it does appear it disallows it being the first or last character (or, as a consequence, the only character) in an atom of the hostname.

Comment: So why does `ping a_a.github.com` work then? Is that still honoring the RFC?