# how to prevent the browser from requesting the assets come from the ajax response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

It might be a silly question, but please consider I'm very newbie in web.

I made an ajax with jquery `$.ajax` , then I put the response in a `<div>` on the current page, and once I do this the browser makes requests for all the assets exist in the ajax response.

for example : this is the plain response came from the ajax

```
   this is a plain text response from my php server
   <div>
   <p> this is the important response,(some value)</p>
   <image src="NOT_important_image.png"></image>
  </div>
```

**how to prevent the browser on the client from requesting the image?**

I tried to make the PHP response `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');`
hoping the browser deal with the response as a plain text not an html, but it still requesting the image.

I can remove the image from the server PHP , but I have to do this on the client side with some client tools (e.g: `javascript`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP or headers returned from the server, but when you include this html-snippet into the DOM, the browser will try to render it.

In your case, if it includes an img-tag and the src-attribute is set, it will try to fetch the contents, to be able to show it to the user.

Remove the img-tag from the html, or send the data as a JSON-object instead, which you can use to populate the correct html with when you would like to render it on the page.

Comment: `Remove the img-tag from the html`  do you mean remove it from the php file before it is sent to the client? or there is a way to remove it after it came to the client and before the browser requests it?.. thanks

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to remove it on the client side other than by manipulating the HTML string *before* its converted to DOM elements.  It would be better if you can to avoid setting the 'src' attribute from the server, using perhaps `data-src` instead.

Comment: @Alnitak when it is converted to DOM? is it when I put it inside the container div on the page like `$("#container_div")[0].innerHTML = response` ?

Comment: yes - merely downloading the content via AJAX and storing it in a string isn't sufficient to trigger the asset loading

Comment: @Alnitak thank you very much ,I removed  it from the response string before adding it to the DOM, and it worked as you said