# Regular expession for domain name

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone please tell regular expression for this:

```
anytext.com
anytext.org
anytext.net
anytext.mil
anytext.gov
```

The requirement is any text given except these domain names (org, net, com, gov, mit) should be invalid.

Cuurently I am giving this regular expression which is not working:

```
/^[\w-\.]+.(?com)(?org)(?mil)(?net)(?edu)(?gov)?$/
```

Comment: Does `location.hostname` not work for you?

Comment: `\w` includes underscores which are not allowed in internet domain names.

Comment: @Richard: [sure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183140/989121)

Comment: Anything wrong with a simple alternation? `(com|org|mil|net|edu|)`

Comment: i want only the above mentioned list to work, anything else after dot(.) should be invalid like : groupinfra.xyz

Comment: @georg Yes, but I should have said *host*names of course (and any URL uses hostnames).

Comment: /^[A-Za-z]+.(com|org|mil|gov)+$/ this worked

Comment: @user3766619 That will match `www.milmilmilgovcomorg` because you allow repetition of the TLD part. It also doesn't match `experts-exchange.com` (I'll now wash my keyboard :-) ).

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```js
var regexp = /^[A-Za-z0-9-\.]+\.(com|org|mil|net|gov)$/

console.log('anytext.com', regexp.test('anytext.com'))
```

Comment: Just an FYI, this is very "anglo-centric".

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly "any text"

Comment: @evolutionxbox Could you explain a little bit?, please

Comment: You're only matching the latin alphabet. What about non-latin alphabet URLs?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Are internationalised characters allowed within .com/.net/.mil/.gov?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I suppose that depends on the problem. If your solution doesn't need non-latin alphabet the solution is more readable. But, How do you match all non-latin allowed chars?

Comment: @dloeda Honestly, I wasn't saying your solution was wrong. I had only hoped to make note that it was a solution which only supports a portion of web users.

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry if I seem rude, it isn't my intention. I search in SO about that and they sort out via Unicode matching. Thanks for question this, really appreciated it