# how to call Web Service with url which contains underscore

Tags: android, ascii, illegalargumentexception, sslhandshakeexception, javax

in my build.gradle I have some thing like that:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
      buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://uat_mobile.xxxxx.com/something/rest/json/"'
    }
}
```

the problem is when I try to call a WS I have this error which appears because of underscore in url:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input to toASCII: uat_mobile.xxxxx.com
```

What is the workaround to this problem please ?

In advance thank you,

Comment: subdomains are not allowed to have an underscore

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14622263/115145 "So underscores in hostnames are a no-no, underscores in domain names are a-ok." What you have here is a hostname, used in a URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced this issue at my organization, they used underscore "_" for sub-domains, I did a workaround for it you can try the following:

- Open your terminal or console command line app.
- Type:

  ping mohammedfathy.wordpress.com

  PING lb.wordpress.com (192.0.78.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
- Use "lb.wordpress.com" instead it will re-route to the same link.
  Also sometimes you can use the IP instead of the link, those steps always works with me.