# Problems with underscore in the domain name

Tags: python, django, docker, dns, docker-compose

Let me first describe my original problem, and solution:

I have several docker-compose files which describe different parts of my application. The parts are developed and deployed independently, so they can not be integrated into a single compose file. But those components need to communicate with each other, and the solution I am using at the moment is to have an external network (bridge) which all services are connecting to. So far so good, and I can indeed connect to my service started with any docker compose file as long as I am connected to the custom bridge network:

```
$ docker run --network=mynet --rm --name ping_test -it xenial-networking bash

root@0319469f7951:/# ping -c 1 proj_web_1
PING proj_web_1 (172.30.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.30.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms

--- proj_web_1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.071/0.071/0.071/0.000 ms
```

Why am using `proj_web_1`? Because that is the DNS entry that docker compose is creating.

This works fine, and nobody cares that underscores are not [that great in domain names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180465/can-domain-name-subdomains-have-an-underscore-in-it).

Nobody ... except `django` it seems:

```
ERROR Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'proj_web_1:8000'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
172.30.0.5 - admin [07/May/2018:05:41:53 +0000] "OPTIONS /api/v1/expansions/ HTTP/1.1" 400 58663 "-" "python-requests/2.18.4"
```

It seems that docker-compose [does not support](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/229) using hyphens instead of underscores.

It could be that [I can workaround this](https://gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de/dlevin/django/commit/1c3c21b38d154eff0286c194711dced2ac39dd3d) by enabling `DEBUG` in my django service.

Is there a cleaner way of enabling this, without running in django debug mode?
Is there a way to tell docker compose to stop using underscores?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `requests.post('http://proj_web1:8000/api/v1/expansions/')` does not complain about the host name, but results in a timeout as expected on my machine. Please provide an MCVE!

Comment: Also see: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18517

Comment: Note that docker compose also allows you to use the service name (so just `web` in your case) to communicate between services in the same stack (which is also the recommendation, as it doesn't make them dependent on the project name used to deploy the stack)

Comment: @KlausD. the problem occurs on the receiving side. You need to have a django-rest based service to see that problem.

Comment: @thaJeztah not possible when using different docker compose: you can not reach services declared by one docker compose from containers started with another docker compose by just using the service name.

Comment: @Timir yes, that is part of the problem. But I am not sure django is to blame, since underscores are really not great in urls.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/472#issuecomment-63514093

Comment: A hostname in the DNS, and hence a domain name, can not have underscores. This is per the DNS standard, see RFC1034 (section 3.5).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The RFCs can say all they want, docker compose is using underscores by default.

Comment: @dangonfast while the short aliases are intended to be used in the same stack, they are done through [network-scoped aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases). Containers from another docker compose can use those aliases if they're connected to the same network. Here's a simple example: https://gist.github.com/thaJeztah/e4f6adff5bb1d9678557611ea1ff5afc

Comment: @thaJeztah that is what I was looking for - and similar to what I mention in my answer below, but using builtin capabilities (no need to define an alias). I could accept that as an answer.

Comment: @dragonfast you and docker can say all they want, the Internet works today because its interoperability is guaranteed by people following RFCs.Why are you trying to avoid underscores if everything works so well with them as you say?

Comment: @dragonfast posted my gist as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Cross-compose network connections

When running a compose project, services are accessible both through their full name (including the project-name prefix, for example, `myproject_web_1`), and through their service name (as specified in the compose-file), for example `web`. The short name is a [network-scoped alias](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases), which means that any container connected to the same network can access the container through this name.

By default, `docker-compose` creates a network for each compose project (`projectname_default`) so that all services in the compose project can communicate. Because that network is created for each project individually, two compose project don't share the same network, and their services are isolated from other compose projects.

It's possible, however, to make compose projects (or individual services in a compose project) share the same network.

#### Example 1 - using a shared network for the whole project

The following compose files specify a custom name for the default network; both compose-files use the `sharednet` network as the default, which means that services for both compose project will be connected to the same network:

Compose file 1 (compose1.yml):

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  compose1service:
    image: busybox
    tty: true

networks:
  default:
    name: sharednet
```

Compose file 2 (compose2.yml):

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  compose2service:
    image: busybox
    tty: true

networks:
  default:
    name: sharednet
```

To illustrate this:

Start both compose files:

```bash
docker-compose -f compose1.yml --project-name=compose1 up -d
docker-compose -f compose2.yml --project-name=compose2 up -d
```

Using the short (`compose2service`) name to ping the `compose2service` from inside the service in the `compose1service` container works;

```bash
docker exec compose1_compose1service_1 ping -c1 compose2service
PING compose2service (172.20.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.20.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.134 ms

--- compose2service ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.134/0.134/0.134 ms
```

And vice-versa:

```bash
docker exec compose2_compose2service_1 ping -c1 compose1service
PING compose1service (172.20.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.20.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.151 ms

--- compose1service ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.151/0.151/0.151 ms
```

As does the full name (including the project prefix);

```bash
docker exec compose2_compose2service_1 ping -c1 compose1_compose1service_1
PING compose1_compose1service_1 (172.20.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.20.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.151 ms

--- compose1_compose1service_1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.151/0.151/0.151 ms
```

#### Example 2 - using a shared network for some service in the project

In this example, both compose projects have their own ("default") network, but in addition, a shared network is added to allow some services to connect to services in the other compose project.

Compose file 1 (compose3.yml):

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  compose3service:
    image: busybox
    tty: true
    networks:
      - default
      - sharednet

  compose3otherservice:
    image: busybox
    tty: true

networks:
  sharednet:
    name: mysharednetwork
```

> **Note**: if you specify which networks a service should be connected to, you override the defaults, which means that the service is no longer automatically connected to the `default` network. Include the `default` network in the list of networks to allow the service to communicate with other services in the compose project.

Compose file 2 (compose4.yml):

```yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  compose4service:
    image: busybox
    tty: true
    networks:
      - default
      - sharednet

  compose4otherservice:
    image: busybox
    tty: true

networks:
  sharednet:
    name: mysharednetwork
```

Start both compose files:

```bash
docker-compose -f compose3.yml --project-name=compose3 up -d
docker-compose -f compose4.yml --project-name=compose4 up -d
```

Again, pinging from the `compose3service` to the `compose4service` service in the other compose project works (either by short name or full name);

```bash
docker exec compose3_compose3service_1 ping -c1 compose4service
PING compose4service (172.22.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.110 ms

--- compose4service ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.110/0.110/0.110 ms


docker exec compose3_compose3service_1 ping -c1 compose4_compose4service_1
PING compose4_compose4service_1 (172.22.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.093 ms

--- compose4_compose4service_1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.093/0.093/0.093 ms
```

However, trying the same to connect to the `compose4otherservice` will fail, because that service is not connected to the `mysharednetwork` network:

```bash
docker exec compose3_compose3service_1 ping -c1 compose4otherservice
ping: bad address 'compose4otherservice'

docker exec compose3_compose3service_1 ping -c1 compose4_compose4otherservice_1
ping: bad address 'compose4_compose4otherservice_1'
```

**Note**:

Care should be taken if two compose projects have a service with the same name (for example, both have a service named `web`). In such situations, `web` may at random resolve to the `web` service from either project.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to workaround the problem by using a network alias, avoiding the underscore:

```
  web:
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=local
      - DJANGO_CONFIGURATION=Develop
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        - REGISTRY
    image: web
    command: ./run-gunicorn.sh
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      spp:
        aliases:
          - projweb
```

And now I can reach it:

```
root@a9c0fde612a1:/# ping -c 1 projweb
PING projweb (172.30.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from svc_web_1.spp (172.30.0.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms

--- projweb ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.082/0.082/0.082/0.000 ms
```