# 400 Error HTTP GET Request between Docker Containers with HTTPURLConnection

Tags: api, docker, tomcat, docker-compose, tomcat8.5

I got two Containers defined in a docker-compose file:

```
 
 tomcat_webserver_api:
  image: tomcat:8
  volumes:
   - ./API/Docker/API.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/API.war
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  depends_on:
   - mysql_database

 tomcat_webserver_anwendung:
  image: tomcat:8
  ports:
   - "8081:8080"
  volumes:
   - ./Anwendung/Docker/Anwendung.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/Anwendung.war
  depends_on:
   - tomcat_webserver_api
  environment:
    API_HOST: tomcat_webserver_api
    API_PORT: 8080
```

Now i want to access the URL `http://tomcat_webserver_api:8080/API/restaurants/Wochentag` from Inside the Java Web Application with an HttpURLConnection.

Issue: It returns an 400 Error

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://tomcat_webserver_api:8080/API/restaurants/Wochentag
```

The Code is like that (The Headers are nearly the same when i try to connect to the URL via curl - this works inside the container huh):

```
    URL api = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://" + "tomcat_webserver_api" + ":" + "8080" +"/API/restaurants/RestaurantSpeisen").build().toURL();

    System.setProperty("http.agent", "curl/7.52.1");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) api.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "localhost");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "curl/7.52.1");
    connection.connect();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new             InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

If i try to connect to `http://172.20.0.3:8080/API/restaurants/Wochentag` i got an 200-ok HTTP Response Code and the JSON-Data.

If i exec the API Container and inspect the logs i can see the 400 GET-Request.

Why is this happen?

`http://172.20.0.3:8080/API/restaurants/Wochentag` - Works
`http://tomcat_webserver_api:8080/API/restaurants/Wochentag` - Won't Work but not with an 404 Error

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did just removing '_' from the name solved it for you Sven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same issue as you, apparently underscore are not allowed as virtualhost, try to remove it, for example, use just tomcatwebserverapi, that should fix your problem.

See [Can (domain name) subdomains have an underscore "_" in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180465/can-domain-name-subdomains-have-an-underscore-in-it) for more information about valid letters in hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

Please give explicit container names a try:

```
tomcat_webserver_api:
  image: tomcat:8
  container_name: tomcat_webserver_api
  volumes:
   - ./API/Docker/API.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/API.war
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  depends_on:
   - mysql_database

tomcat_webserver_anwendung:
  container_name: tomcat_webserver_app
  image: tomcat:8
  ports:
   - "8081:8080"
  volumes:
   - ./Anwendung/Docker/Anwendung.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/Anwendung.war
  depends_on:
   - tomcat_webserver_api
  environment:
    API_HOST: tomcat_webserver_api
    API_PORT: 8080
```

The "local only" configuration needs explicit container names to activate Docker's name lookup mechanism. In Swarm mode you wouldn't need to set container names.