# Regular expression for “Url Cannot start with www in prefix and white spaces

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Regular expression for “Url Cannot start with www in prefix and white spaces"
please help me frnds.

eg:goole.com is correct

eg:www.google.com is not accepted

eg: www.google.com is not accepted

prefix not www. and not start with whitespace -------->show fail

googlewwwwwwwwww.com ---->show success

Thanks in advance...

Comment: should see this, might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063213/regular-expression-for-validating-dns-label-host-name

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex solution.

```
string str = "goole.com";
Uri tempUri;
if (!str.StartsWith(" ") //shouldn't start with space
    && !str.StartsWith("www") //shoudn't start with www
    && Uri.TryCreate(str, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out tempUri) //should be 
                                                                   //a valid Uri
    )
{
    //valid url
}
else
{
    //invalid url
}
```

Comment: hi habib i am using regular expressions prefix should not www.  and  whitespace so help me and using regular expressions

Comment: @user1858830, I am no expert with regex, why can't you use this check in your code ?