# regular expression for the address of domain name server

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regular expression for DNS.

My requirement is that the valid DNS should be:

1. www.x.y
2. www.t.x.y
3. www.s.t.x.y

Only 4 dots(`.`) are allowed. I have tried this regular expression but its not working. Please suggest.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-z0-9]+.[a-zA-z0-9]$
```

Comment: Why don't you use a parser?

Comment: once I ve found this beautidul service, it may help. http://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: `.` is usually a special character that matches any character.  You probably need to escape it since you want a `.` and not the meta-character.

Comment: @StNickolas That is an amazing website.  +1 for pointing that out.

Comment: @anonymous will [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063213/regular-expression-for-validating-dns-label-host-name) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple regex could be something along

```
^www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)?$
```

Three points:

- the point (`.`) is a special character and must be escaped (`\.`)
- we need optional clauses for the last two sections.
- your examples start with `www`, so you need to include this in order to use the start mark (`^`)

Answer (score 1):

try this link

[Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

- Regular Expression Test Page

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
str.matches("www(\\.\\w+){2,4}")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

`^(www\.|)(([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.){1,4}[a-z]+$`