# Kubernetes Replication Controller name is not RFC1035 compliant

Tags: kubernetes

While trying out a sample kubernetes python client from https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/blob/master/examples/exec.py I get an error saying that the replication controller name must match the regex a-z0-9?(\.a-z0-9?)* when I try out a name "My-Whole-World". As per the regex printed in the error message this is expected, though when check the Kubernetesdocumentation page at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/run-stateless-ap-replication-controller/#resizing-a-replication-controller I see that the name must be RFC1035 compliant. Now the regex printed in the error message does not look compliant to RFC1035 regex ([Regular Expression for validating DNS label ( host name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063213/regular-expression-for-validating-dns-label-host-name)). This looks like a bug in kubernetes. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

The document seems to have old invalid information. `ReplicationControllers` conform to `RFC 1123`.

**Code Traversal:**

To validate replication controller this is used [`ValidateReplicationControllerName`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/validation/validation.go#L240) which is basically a function called [`NameIsDNSSubdomain`](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/api/validation/generic.go#L36)

This in turn calls [`IsDNS1123Subdomain`](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/util/validation/validation.go#L117) so this final function is doing validation based on RFC 1123.

There a line says:

> a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character