# Bash Regex needs attention

Tags: regex, bash

I do not know that this is a duplicate question. I have, as I always do, research until I do not have a workable solution or have not figured it out by myself. I am not frivolous.
I can split this string at the delimiter in minutes. That is not why I am here. I am security conscious. This is user input from command line input. I am trying to verify and validate user input and I do not consider that a wasted effort.
I'm doing something fairly simple, however my level of expertise can't figure this out.
I am taking a command line option input from a script and it goes into three variables.

```
$LOCAL_FILE
$DESTINATION_USER
$DESTINATION_FILE
```

I'll be using scp and /etc/hosts to verify before processing.

I take `$DESTINATION_USER` which is example: user@xu4-node1-2 and run the user thru my not working regex (Which I use elsewhere in an if conditional and it works fine); to verify format and remove the "user@" part so that I can awk /etc/hosts to get the IP of the user so that I can verify and put the hostname and ip into an associative array (That is used for a similar reason).

```
sUSER=$DESTINATION_USER
[[ "$sUSER" =~ "([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))*$" ]]
ip=$(awk '/^[[:space:]]*($|#)/{next}/'$sUSER'/{print $1; exit}' /etc/hosts)
declare -A dUSER[$ip]=$sUSER
```

For example, I need to verify user input "user@xu4-node1-2" and loose the "user@" part so all I have is "xu4-node1-2" so I can give it to the awk to give me the ip. My regex however gives me the whole "user@xu4-node1-2"

I use the regex in this:

```
elif [[ $i =~ ^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))* ]]; then
```

and it works fine.

** Update

I was able to complete this code to resolve my problem. I am posting it here in case it can help anyone else. I included verification and validation of user input, un-tainting it
and though it's not in this snippet, input from the hosts file as well. I also included some error handling.

```
    sUSER=$DESTINATION_USER
    sUSER="${sUSER#"${sUSER%%[![:space:]A-Za-z0-9._%+-]*}@"}"
    if [[ $sUSER =~ ^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))*$ ]]; then
      ip=$(awk '/^[[:space:]]*($|#)/{next}/'$sUSER'/{print $1; exit}' /etc/hosts)
      if ! [[ $ip ]]; then
        printf "\n${LtRED} --> Error - No reference IP address found in /etc/hosts file for $sUSER\n --> Make sure that your hosts file is properly formatted${RESET}\n\n"
        exit 1
      fi
      declare -A dUSER[$ip]=$sUSER
    else
      printf "\n${LtRED} --> Remote user address ( $sUSER ) is not formatted properly - Try Again${RESET}\n\n"
      exit 1
  fi
```

Comment: A regex is overkill. Just split on `@`.

Comment: And the difference between the one that works and the one that does not is the double quotes. Remove the double quotes of the regex

Comment: John Kugelman... I've considered splitting the string at the "@", but thank you for your input. I am aware that this is considered user input and I'm trying to be somewhat moderately security conscious and taint myself. I do not consider it overkill.

Comment: kvantour thank you for your feedback. However I have been unable to make the regex functional by any type or means of quoting or the lack of any quoting.

Comment: I would like to add that there is a fairly complete discussion of validating here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-dns-hostname-or-ip-address and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063213/regular-expression-for-validating-dns-label-host-name those are a few places I have been researching.